# Interpret 2 separate JSON return objects

Tags: php, json, angular

I have am using oauth backend to generate a valid token after login, but I return 2 separate json objects because I cant link them with PHP when i create the token and return the data of the user from my database so I get a string like so:

> {"id":"1","email":"test@test.com","username":"user","firstname":"john","lastname":"doe"}
>   {"access_token":"d0f8...2a","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":null}

As you can see I get 2 separate JSON objects, they are all on one line aswell so I cant split by new line, plus I feel splitting this data would just make a mess

In Angular 2 whats the best way to just get 2 JSON objects from this?

This is how I return the data:

```
login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                if(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
                /*this.authenticationService.token = (data.token)
                if(data.token) {
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', data.token);
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.router.navigate(['/user']);
                }else{

                }*/
            },  //changed
            (err)=> {
                console.log(err);
                this.error = 'Username or password is incorrect';
                this.loading = false;},
            ()=>console.log("Done")
        );
    }
```

Comment: because I cant link them with PHP when i create the token and return the data of the user from my database so I get a string like so ? Where the code is written for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just can put an extra character (for egg: ' **;** ') betwen the two string that represents the two object, you can parse it by spliting by this character:

```js
var str = '{"id":"1","email":"test@test.com","username":"user","firstname":"john","lastname":"doe"};{"access_token":"d0f8...2a","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":null}';

var str = '[' + str.split(';').join(',') + ']';

var objects = JSON.parse(str);
var obj1 = objects[0];
var obj2 = objects[1];
console.log("obj1: ", obj1);
console.log("obj2: ", obj2);
```

In case you want to play with ES6, it's even shorter:

```js
var str = '{"id":"1","email":"test@test.com","username":"user","firstname":"john","lastname":"doe"};{"access_token":"d0f8...2a","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":null}';
var [obj1, obj2] = str.split(";").map(el => JSON.parse(el));
console.log("obj1: ", obj1);
console.log("obj2: ", obj2);
```

Comment: OP says that they are not... `... they are all on one line aswell ...`

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap those 2 objects to array or object, and return that instead from your server, so you will have valid JSON.

Instead of your payload, return something like this:

```
{
  "profile": {"id":"1","email":"test@test.com","username":"user","firstname":"john","lastname":"doe"},
  "auth": {"access_token":"d0f8...2a","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":null}
}
```

Something like this in your PHP:

```
// your current object representation of the JSON you are sending
$profile = ...;
$auth = ...;

$wrapper = new \stdClass;
$wrapper->profile = $profile;
$wrapper->auth = $auth;

$json = json_encode($wrapper);

// and just return the $json variable instead of concatenating those 2
```

To overcome the issue you noted in comments, you could use output buffering:

```
ob_start(); // start gathering the output of `echo`
$server->handleTokenRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobal‌​s())->send(); // call the method that echoes
$auth = ob_get_clean();

// now you have the JSON string in $auth
$wrapper = new \stdClass;
$wrapper->profile = $profile;
$wrapper->auth = json_decode($auth); // use `json_decode` to parse it to object

$json = json_encode($wrapper); // create the JSON again
```

One note at the end - this is definitely the right approach, but to answer your original question about parsing the two objects - you could simply split the string on `}{`, that can not occurre in valid JSON unless you concatenate more of them.

```js
var doubleJSON = '{"id":"1","email":"test@test.com","username":"user","firstname":"john","lastname":"doe"} {"access_token":"d0f8...2a","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":null}';

var temp = doubleJSON.split(/\}\W+\{/); // use regexp, that allows white space character between `}` and `{`
var profile = JSON.parse(temp[0] + '}'); // add the `}` character to the end, that is missing because of the split call
var auth = JSON.parse('{' + temp[1]); // add the `{` character to the front, that is missing because of the split call

console.log(profile);
console.log(auth);
```

Comment: I want to do this and that was my first thought but im not sure how I can turn this call `if($userclass->validUser($email,$password)) {
            $server->handleTokenRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
        }` (that call echos a json object) and combine it with my results

Comment: I see. You have 2 options, one is to use http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php, the other is to split those 2 things in 2 requests.

Comment: I added example with output buffering + also a way to parse those 2 JSONs